Algolia on Class Component React Native?
I am adding Algolia to an old app using class component react-native v0.72.10, React v18.2. Every single tutorial uses hooks. How would I change my code to work with v0.72.10 react-native? Ideally I would have a search client and infinite hits. I am not able update react native for this scope of work, and all the tutorials on Algolia's website run react >= 16.
        <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient}>
          <View
          >
            <SearchComponent callBack={this.searchResults} />

class SearchComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchValue: this.props.currentRefinement,
    };
    this.searchRef = React.createRef();
    this.time = null;
    this.query = useSearchBox().query;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (
      this.props.currentRefinement !== prevProps.currentRefinement &&
      !this.searchRef.current?.isFocused()
    ) {
      this.setState({ searchValue: this.props.currentRefinement });
    }
  }

  setQuery = (newQuery) => {
    this.props.refine(newQuery);
    this.props.callBack(newQuery);
  };

None of this works because I can't use hooks to connect a searchbox. Cant find any documentation on the old connectors repo, nor a version that doesn't use hooks.
I have code from a functional component with hooks that works, but I cant seem to figure out how to make it a class component:
<InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient}>
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 30 }}>
        <SearchComponent callBack={(value) => searchResults(value)} />
    </View>
    <Index indexName="topics">
         <InfiniteHits
            hitComponent={TopicCard}
            indexName="topics"/>
    </Index>
</InstantSearch>

const SearchComponent = (props) => {
    const searchRef = useRef(null);
    const { query, refine } = useSearchBox(props);
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(query);

    function setQuery(newQuery) {
        refine(newQuery);
        props.callBack(newQuery);
    }

    if (query !== searchValue && !searchRef.current?.isFocused()) {
        setSearchValue(query);
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                searchRef.current.focus();
            }}
            style={[searchStyles.inputContainer, styles.shadow]}
        >
            <SearchIcon />
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    clearTimeout(time);
                    setSearchValue(text);
                    time = setTimeout(() => {
                        setQuery(text);
                    }, 100);
                }}
.......

export function InfiniteHits({ hitComponent: Card, indexName, ...props }) {
    const { hits, isLastPage, showMore } = useInfiniteHits(props);
<FlatList
                    style={{ paddingHorizontal: 30 }}
                    contentContainerStyle={
                        indexName === "topics" ? { paddingRight: 50 } : { paddingRight: 0 }
                    }
                    data={hits}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.objectID}
                    horizontal={indexName === "topics"}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ margin: 10 }} />}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    onEndReached={() => {
                        if (!isLastPage) {
                            showMore();
                        }
                    }}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {.....

I have tried passing the queries in props, and on mount setting different states to the props. I have tried using the new hooks, and that did not work either. Completely lost.

Are you updating old React code to current standards... or are you trying to use current React code in an older codebase? What specific React version are you using? If it's at least React 16.8.4 then you should be able to use React hooks. Please [edit] to clarify what exactly you are trying to do and what the exact specific issue or problem is that you face.

Edited. Im on 0.72.10, and need to stay on that version.

That's React-Native. And I misspoke a bit, React 16.8.0 is the React version that introduces hooks. What version of React are you using? Can you [edit] to include the code you tried to use that uses the React hooks you need to use if you want to use Algolia? See [mcve]. It looks like react-native v0.72.10 was released this year.... there should be no reason at all not to be able to use React hooks, they've been available since 2019.

Updated. Im using React 18 - also put some snippets of functional component code that works. If you could help turn it to class, that would be great.

That looks like a good start, though the code is incomplete. Can you clarify what/where exactly you are stuck and need help?

Hey Drew, I actually ended up figuring it out with your help. Sounds goofy, but I was actually unaware you could use new React inside an old React-Native. From there I just followed the regular Algolia documentation. Thanks for pointing that out to me!
